# WebdriverIO Cucumber How to use context from step in hooks?

Tags: javascript, cucumber, webdriver-io

WebdriverIO Cucumber How to use context from step in hooks? For example I want to delete in hooks specific file created in steps.

I tried to delete file using fs.ulinkSync(this.filename). File was created in steps this.filename=pathToFile.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.